# How to sort first half in ascending and second half in descending order in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I have a python list [1,2,3,4,5] I have to print [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1].

Please suggest how to do in loop(while or for)

Comment: is the list always sorted by default? or you need to sort it?

Comment: normal way is sort the list and reverse the list and combine the 2 list. Please advice in loop way

Comment: it is sorted list

Comment: @sat this is wasteful, no need to sort the list twice

Comment: @DeepSpace, I got it..

Comment: why negative marks, I told in the comment, sort and reverse i already done.by the way @Netwave Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> res = []
>>> for e in reversed(l):
...     res.append(e)
...     res.insert(0, e)
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In case the list is not sorted, instead of `reversed` use `sorted` with the reverse flag set to `True`

```
>>> l = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
>>> res = []
>>> for e in sorted(l, reverse=True):
...     res.append(e)
...     res.insert(0, e)
... 
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

And, for a more efficient version I would suggest using iterators:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = sorted([4, 3, 1, 5, 2])
>>> res = list(itertools.chain(l, reversed(l)))
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: @Netwave, This will fail in case list is  `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`

Comment: @sat, just in case the list is not sorted, then he need to use `sorted` instead of `reversed`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a loop. Just sort and concatenate source list with reversed list.

```
a = [2, 1, 5, 4, 3]
a = sorted(a)
print(a + a[::-1])
```

Comment: @Netwave its false. Code valid on `python3` too.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it's sorted list (right?), so do:

```
print(l+l[::-1])
```

Or:

```
print(l+reversed(l))
```

Both cases, the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a, b = eval('[1,2,3,4,5],'*2);b.reverse();print(a+b)
```

**output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: `eval` is bad practice

Comment: What is the claim behind that?